# Firestore Array Query More than 10 Elements (Pagination)

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

I'm trying to fetch all the guests of a party which is stored in an array called "PhoneNumbers." Each invite adds that persons phone number to the array. If there are more than 10 invites the app crashes because that is the Firestore limitation.

```
fileprivate func fetchGuests() {
        print("hi hi")
        guard !fetchedAllUsers, !fetchingMoreUsers else { return }
        fetchingMoreUsers = true
        tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 1), with: .none)

        let partyUID = self.party?.partyUID ?? ""
        navigationItem.title = "\(party?.partyName ?? "") Guests"

        Firestore.firestore().collection("parties").document(partyUID).getDocument { (snap, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print(err, "fook")
            }
            guard let partyDict = snap?.data() else {return}
            let party = Party(dictionary: partyDict)

            self.phoneNumbers = party.guestPhoneNumbers as! [String]
            print(self.phoneNumbers)


        var query: Query
            if let lastFetchedNumber = self.lastFetchedNumber {
                query = Firestore.firestore().collection("users").whereField("PhoneNumber", in: self.phoneNumbers).order(by: "Full Name").start(after: [lastFetchedNumber]).limit(to: 9)

        } else {
            query = Firestore.firestore().collection("users").whereField("PhoneNumber", in: self.phoneNumbers).order(by: "Full Name").limit(to: 9)
        }

        // Change logic where gender variable is just the where field firebase thing
        query.getDocuments { (snapshot, err) in ......yadayadayada
```

Anyone have any ideas of how to work around the max 10 rule?
Maybe should I add another array to the collection called PhoneNumbers2 for guests 9-18 and PhoneNumbers3 for 19-28?

Let me know if you have any ideas! (I can't add a new collection called guests because this app allows you to invite people you are not authenticated and I need to be able to query these numbers with out them having a UID if that makes sense)

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: I think the approach here is the issue and I am curious what Firestore limitation you're referring to? A query can return 1 to an infinite number of documents; the only limitation is your code telling it to only return a certain number `.limit(to: 9)` and that won't cause a crash.  Can you more clearly explain what the purpose of the code is? Is it that you have a list of phone numbers and you want to get the matching guest information based on that list?

Comment: My apologies. the firebase limitation is that you cannot have an array that has more than 10 elements when you use the whereField("Field", in: [array])

Comment: Ah - but that shouldn't be necessary at all. Again - the question is; do you have a list of phone numbers and want to read in those users data? If so, the data is not structured correctly to allow for that. For example, you could have a field within each node called *invited_to: party_1*, so when a user is invited to a party, update their documents *invited_to* field with *party_1*. Then query for all users that were invited to *party_1* and you're done. If you can clarify the question and perhaps give us a snippet of your structure, we may be more help. When replying to a comment use @Jay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1: Add array extension to get chunk of array**

```
extension Array {
func chunked(into size: Int) -> [[Element]] {
    return stride(from: 0, to: count, by: size).map {
        Array(self[$0 ..< Swift.min($0 + size, count)])
    }
}
}
```

**Step 2: Split your content to chunks**

```
    let chunkedArray = ids.chunked(into: 10)
```

**Step 3: Iterate chunk array and execute your firestore query**

```
 chunkedArray.forEach
 { ids in

   let query = db.collection("TABLE_NAME").whereField("KEY_ID" , in: ids )
 //your firestore query request here 
 }
```

Comment: This solution will perhaps change the future, thanks to you. I can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get rid of the "query = " part of it and just get documents directly in your if-else statement. This returned 17 documents in my test. I Used different collection names and field names but exact same structure
.

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("users").whereField("PhoneNumber", in: array).order(by: "Full Name").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        print(snapshot?.documents.count)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the firebase documentation it support up to 10 ids only in the where field, For querying more than 10 elements either we need to query each document individually or split array to chunks of 10 ids.

For querying each items individually. Check the code below,

```
let usersPromise = [];

usersIds.map((id) => {
    usersPromise.push(firestore.collection("users").doc(id).get());
});
        
Promise.all(usersPromise).then((docs) => {
    const users = docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
    
    // do your operations with users list
});
```